# I need to force a refresh of custom.css in the Thesis Framework

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, wordpress-thesis-theme

Does anyone know the best way to refresh custom.css in Thesis? I'm running into a problem where some of my css isn't getting implemented due to browser caching of custom.css. I tried adding a variable to the filename like "custom.css?v=1" and while this works, it gives me an error every time I load the page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable CSS caching by adding this filter to the custom_functions.php file.

```
function cache_customcss()
{
return true;
}

add_filter('thesis_cache_query','cache_customcss');
```